# Android studio fails to install apk into Xiaomi Note5A (Redmi) (Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED:)

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, xiaomi

Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

Cannot install APK from Android studio to this device. It prompt an error at the last moment telling me to Uninstall the App First then Install (Existing app may refusing) wheres the app is not installed yet.

Developer Option On
USB Debugging On

What else can I Do?

Comment: What happens when you click the OK button in the dialog that asks if you want to uninstall the app first? If this doesn't work, please copy and paste the entire error message here in your question.

Comment: @Zoe I have updated the question, please see.

Comment: Zoe, Enzokie, Mike M., techraf, gnat Question updated, share your Idea though I have solved it with little more mining. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the 100% working solution for this issue. It works in every xiaomi device and its tested -

Go to Settings -> Permissions -> Install via USB: Uncheck your App if it's listed.
Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Privacy: Check the Unknown Sources option.
Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options: Check the Install via USB option.
Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options:Enable view attribute inspection
Finally Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options:Turn off MIUI optimization.
And then restart your device and whoooaaaa it will work i guaranteee..

Answer (score 1):

When you install an app via usb on mi mobile, it display following dialog.. don't you see this,
[image: see picture]

if you are able to see this, select "Remember my choice" and tap on "Install" button.

Comment: didnt showed anythying like it, as it was one of my official device may be it was configured once by other user, when it came to my workstation I didnt got anything like this, however the problem was solved . see my answer below. thanks.